# Android Linear Layout Weight Programmatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I want to add three linear layouts to an activity programatically each of same width. the problem is i am not able to set the weights of these layouts programmatically. I could do this within xml, but I want to do this in program.
here is what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here its the solution

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 100);
    lp.weight = 1;
```

See Full Solution

```
LinearLayout ll1, ll2, ll3;
    /* Find these LinearLayout by ID 
     i.e ll1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll1);
     */

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 100);
    lp.weight = 1;
    ll1.setLayoutParams(lp);
    ll2.setLayoutParams(lp);
    ll3.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Worked like charm, thanks for quick response. However I had to modify it a bit like this >> LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.weight = 1;

Answer (score 7):

Use `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(int width, int height, float weight)` to set weights when setting layout params to the subviews

Answer (score 4):

Do this way..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtNote = (LinedEditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNote);
    lnr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnr);
    LinearLayout l1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout l2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout l3 = new LinearLayout(this);
    l1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light);
    l2.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);
    l3.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
    lnr.addView(l1, param);
    lnr.addView(l2, param);
    lnr.addView(l3, param);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by setting layout weight property for your individual linear layouts, pass it in LinearLayout - LayoutParams constructor:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParam(
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
```

or

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                         0,
                         LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
```

Hope it may help you !